# SQL Query simple question

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering if I'm missing something here:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT usr.id, 
CONCAT(usr.username, '".PHP_EOL."' ) as username 
FROM #__ads AS a 
RIGHT JOIN #__users 
WHERE gid= '19' AS usr  
    ON usr.id = a.userid 
ORDER BY usr.username";
```

It works when I remove the WHERE gid = '19' part, is it in the wrong place? The gid column only exists in the __users table.

Thank you!

Edit: got it, just needed to put the Where clause right before the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause must come after any joins:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT usr.id
             , CONCAT(usr.username, '".PHP_EOL."' ) as username
        FROM #__ads AS a
        RIGHT JOIN #__users AS usr
        ON usr.id = a.userid 
        WHERE gid= '19'
        ORDER BY usr.username";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want just the row(s) from `#__users` where `usr.gid= '19'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.id, 
                CONCAT(usr.username, '".PHP_EOL."' ) as username 
FROM #__ads AS a 
RIGHT JOIN #__users as usr  ON usr.id = a.userid  
WHERE usr.gid= '19' 
ORDER BY usr.username
```

The alternative

```
SELECT DISTINCT usr.id, 
                CONCAT(usr.username, '".PHP_EOL."' ) as username 
FROM #__ads AS a 
RIGHT JOIN #__users as usr  ON usr.id = a.userid  
                            AND usr.gid= '19' 
ORDER BY usr.username
```

Would give you all rows from  `#__users` but only join on those matching `usr.gid= '19'`